# Time zone inconsistency in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

I have a column in a table of type timestamp. I tried to update it using different methods, and I got inconsistent results:

```
Current time: ET 14:30 pm.
Using dateof(now()) -> Get 19:30 pm
Using string value 'xxxx-xx-xx 14:30:00' -> Get 18:30 pm.
```

I'm using

```
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.2-SNAPSHOT | CQL spec 3.4.0 | Native protocol v4]
```

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the timezone for cqlsh with an environment variable called TZ.

For example if you set TZ to UTC, then times would be displayed in GMT time.

There's not enough information to tell what you're doing to get those results, but it sounds like somehow your environment is confusing cqlsh about what time zone you are in.